# Support for Type Abbreviations / Type Aliases

Tags: language-ext

Please forgive me if I've missed something basic, but does language-ext have support for type abbreviations / type aliases as described [here](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-abbreviations/)?

In one of my projects I've attempted a rudimentary implementation which allows inheriting from the basic types string, int, long, decimal, Guid etc. This allows 'orderNumber' on your POCO to be strongly represented as opposed to just being an int.

It would be desirable to have  json.net custom JsonConverters as well for serialization.

Are these a regular feature of functional languages, or just an F# thing? If the former is true and language-ext doesn't have an implementation is it something I could help add?

Cheers :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the generic types `NewType` and `FloatType` might be what you are looking for.  On the [Language Ext GitHub home page](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext), search for "newtype".

Also, feel free to ask questions like this on the Language Ext GitHub by [creating a new issue](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext/issues/new).

Comment: Thanks for that. Perfect. I'm excited about this library. Thanks to everyone involved!